# Best way to handle changing 'mode' of a python class

Tags: python, class, properties

So i'm trying to create a module for high level motor control, and it is going to contain a bunch of instances of the `node` class. Upon creation, each node will have a `nodeID`, `busID`, and `operatingMode`.

Upon initialization of a node object, I send a CAN frame to the motor saying "hey, this is the operating mode you want to be in". The command that does that is called cansend.

I've roughed out the code (don't have it handy) for your reference:

```
def cansend(nodeID,busID,value):
'''sends a CAN frame with a particular value to a specific node'''


class node(object):
    def __init__(self,nodeID,busID,operatingMode):
        self.nodeID=nodeID
        self.busID=busID
        self.operatingMode=operatingMode
        cansend(self.nodeID,self.busID,operatingMode
```

The problem that I've got is that if I want to change the operating mode on the fly (and I do), then it seems that I have to create separate function, maybe something like this:

```
    def setOperatingMode(self,operatingMode):
        cansend(self.nodeID,self.busID,operatingMode)
```

It seems a little redundant to create this line both in the `__init__` method and the `setOperatingMode` method. I recently discovered the @property tag but don't see particularly how it could be used here, however I do feel that there is a better way.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your `node` instances each represent a physical motor that they're supposed to control. The `cansend` function takes care of the low-level communication between the code and the motor itself. You want to make it so that changes to the `Node`'s `operatingMode` value get sent to the motor.

Here's how you can do this with a `property`:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, nodeID, busID, operatingMode)
        self.nodeID = nodeID
        self.busID = busID
        self.operatingMode = operatingMode

    @property
    def operatingMode(self):
        return self._operatingMode

    @operatingMode.setter
    def operatingMode(self, mode):
        self._operatingMode = mode
        cansend(self.nodeID, self.busID, mode)
```

Now, any time you assign to `operatingMode` on a `Node` instance (including in the `Node` constructor itself!), the `cansend` function will be called with the new value.

Answer (score 1):

The global `cansend()` function is generic and can be called from anywhere so I'd probably leave this function as-is unless every invocation of `cansend()` is from a node class.

You could add a `cansend()` method to your class which uses the stored instance variables as input, rather than having them set as parameters.  Furthermore, if you're interested in using properties you could have the `operatingMode` configured as a property as you suggested.

Here's an example refactor:

```
def cansend(nodeID,busID,value):
'''sends a CAN frame with a particular value to a specific node'''


class node(object):
    def __init__(self,nodeID,busID,operatingMode):
        self.nodeID = nodeID
        self.busID = busID
        self._operatingMode = operatingMode
        self.send_can_mode()

    def send_can_mode(self):
        """Send current operating mode to node on CAN bus."""
        cansend(self.nodeID, self.busID, self._operatingMode)

    @property
    def operatingMode(self):
        """Return current operating mode."""
        return self._operatingMode

    @operatingMode.setter
    def operatingMode(self, value):
        """Modify operating mode.  Update remote node if mode changes."""
        if value == self._operatingMode:
            return
        self._operatingMode = value
        self.send_can_mode()
```

When you want to change modes, you can do `node.operatingMode = newMode` and if the mode has changed from the previous state, the new mode will be automatically sent.

The global `cansend()` is only called from the `send_can_mode()` method so you could integrate the global `cansend()` into your class if desired.